# Finite Dimensional Vector Space and its subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra

Here is the problem.

> Suppose $V$ is a finite dimensional vector space and $U, W$ are subspaces of $V$. ($U, W \leq V$) Also let $\mathfrak{B}, \mathfrak{C}$ be a basis of $U, W$, respectively.
>
> $\quad $Prove that if $U\cap W = 0$ (zero vector space), $\mathfrak{B} \cap \mathfrak{C} = \emptyset$ and $\mathfrak{B} \cup \mathfrak{C}$ is a basis of $U+W$.

So I tried by letting $\mathfrak{B}, \mathfrak{C}$ be a basis of given vector spaces $U$ and $W$. It really occurs to me that I should be using something related to $U\cap W = 0$ (zero vector space) but I can't really get anything out of this. So I cannot get a grasp of where to start from.

It feels like I might have to use the Basis Extension Theorem. But I also don't really get why this might be true. Can I get a hint on this or at least a intuitive reason for why this might be true?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It should be clear that $\mathfrak{B}\cup\mathfrak{C}$ *spans* $U+W$.  The only thing really missing is for $\mathfrak{B}$ to be linearly independent from $\mathfrak{C}$.  Continue with contrapositive/contradiction.  Suppose that it wasn't... then without loss of generality, there is some linear combination of vectors that results in the zero vector with at least some constants of the vectors nonzero.  What happens if you move some of these vectors around to the other side of the equality?  Can we conclude something about $U\cap W$?  Similarly, what if $v\in\mathfrak{B}\cap\mathfrak{C}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, note that $0\notin\mathfrak{B}$ and $0\notin\mathfrak{C}$, and
$$\mathfrak{B}\cap\mathfrak{C}\subset U\cap W=\{0\}.$$
It follows that $\mathfrak{B}\cap\mathfrak{C}=\emptyset$.

To show that $\mathfrak{B}\cup\mathfrak{C}$ is a basis, you need to show that

i) $\mathfrak{B}\cup\mathfrak{C}$ spans $U+W$, and

ii) $\mathfrak{B}\cup\mathfrak{C}$ is linearly independent.

To show (i), note that any $v\in U+W$ can be written as $v=u+w$ for some $u\in U$ and $w\in W$. Well,
$$u=\sum_{b\in\mathfrak{B}}\lambda_bb\;\;\;\mbox{and}\;\;\;w=\sum_{c\in\mathfrak{C}}\mu_cc$$
for some $\lambda_b,\mu_c\in F$. Therefore,
$$v=u+w=\sum_{b\in\mathfrak{B}}\lambda_bb+\sum_{c\in\mathfrak{C}}\mu_cc\in\mathrm{Span}(\mathfrak{B}\cup\mathfrak{C})$$
showing that $\mathfrak{B}\cup\mathfrak{C}$ spans $U+V$.

To show (ii), assume
$$
\sum_{b\in\mathfrak{B}}\lambda_bb+\sum_{c\in\mathfrak{C}}\mu_cc=0.
$$
Then, 
$$\sum_{b\in\mathfrak{B}}\lambda_bb=-\sum_{c\in\mathfrak{C}}\mu_cc.
$$
The left hand side of the equation above belongs to $U$, while the right hand side belongs to $W$. Hence, both sides belong to $U\cap W=\{0\}$. That is,
$$\sum_{b\in\mathfrak{B}}\lambda_bb=\sum_{c\in\mathfrak{C}}\mu_cc=0.
$$
Since $\mathfrak{B}$ is linearly independent, all $\lambda_b=0$ and, since $\mathfrak{C}$ is linearly independent, all $\mu_c=0$. Hence $\mathfrak{B}\cup\mathfrak{C}$ is linearly independent, as required.

Answer (score 2):

A sketch of a proof . $\mathfrak{B}$ and $\mathfrak{C}$ are subsets of $U$ and $W,$ respectively, so if $U$ and $W$ are disjoint, so are $\mathfrak{B}$ and $\mathfrak{C}.$ Again since $U$ and $W$ are disjoint, any vector of $U+W$ has a unique expression as $u+w,$ where $u\in U$ and $w \in W:$ if $u+w=u'+w',$ then $u-u'=w-w',$ which belongs to both $U$ and $W,$ so must be the zero vector, whence $u=u'$ and $w=w'.$ Consequently, $u+w=0$ implies $u=w=0,$ $0$ being the zero vector.

For an arbitrary $u+w,$ $u,$ (resp. $w$) is a unique linear combination of the vectors in $\mathfrak{B},$ (resp. $\mathfrak{C}),$ so $\mathfrak{B} \cup \mathfrak{C}$ spans $U+W.$ That this set is linearly independent can be shown using the argument at the end of the first paragraph.